# Is it possible to return part of a struct by reference?

Tags: struct, reference, rust

Consider the following two structs:

```
pub struct BitVector<S: BitStorage> {
    data: Vec<S>,
    capacity: usize,
    storage_size: usize
}

pub struct BitSlice<'a, S: BitStorage> {
    data: &'a [S],
    storage_size: usize
}
```

Where `BitStorage` is practically a type that is restricted to all unsigned integers (u8, u16, u32, u64, usize).

How to implement the `Deref` trait? (`BitVector<S>` derefs to `BitSlice<S>` similar to how `Vec<S>` derefs to `&[S]`)

I have tried the following (Note that it doesn't compile due to issues with lifetimes, but more importantly because I try to return a value on the stack as a reference):

```
impl<'b, S: BitStorage> Deref for BitVector<S> {
    type Target = BitSlice<'b, S>;

    fn deref<'a>(&'a self) -> &'a BitSlice<'b, S> {
        let slice = BitSlice {
            data: self.data,
            storage_size: self.storage_size,
        };
        &slice
    }
}
```

I am aware that it is possible to return a field of a struct by reference, so for example I could return `&Vec<S>` or `&usize` in the `Deref` trait, but is it possible to return a `BitSlice` noting that I essentially have all the data in the `BitVector` already as `Vec<S>` can be transformed into `&[S]` and `storage_size` is already there?

I would think this is possible if I could create a struct using both values and somehow tell the compiler to ignore the fact that it is a struct that is created on the stack and instead just use the existing values, but I have got no clue how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Deref` is required to return a reference. A reference *always* points to some existing memory, and any local variable will not exist long enough. While there are, in theory, some sick tricks you could play to create a new object in `deref` and return a reference to it, all that I'm aware of result in a memory leak. Let's ignore these technicalities and just say it's plain impossible.

Now what? You'll have to change your API. `Vec` can implement `Deref` because it derefs to `[T]`, not to `&[T]` or anything like that. You may have success with the same strategy: Make `BitSlice<S>` an unsized type containing only a slice `[S]`, so that the return type is `&'a BitSlice<S>`. This assume the `storage_size` member is not needed. But it seems that this refers to the number of bits that are logically valid (i.e., can be accessed without extending the bit vector) — if so, that seems unavoidable<sup>1</sup>.

The other alternative, of course, is to not implement a `Deref`. Inconvenient, but if your slice data type is too far from an actual slice, it may be the only option.

[RFC PR #1524](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1524) that proposed custom dynamically-sized types, then you could have a type `BitSlice<S>` that is like a slice but can have additional contents such as `storage_size`. However, this doesn't exist yet and it's far from certain if it ever will.

<sup>1</sup> The `capacity` member on `BitVector`, however, seems pointless. Isn't that just `sizeof S * 8`?

Comment: You are correct in your assumption that `storage_size` is not needed, it's just `std::mem::size_of::<S>() * 8`, however I am afraid that `capacity` is needed as you could allocate a bit vector that is not a multiply of the backing storage, ie. backing storage is u32 and you want to allocate 50 bits, though it might be reasonable to force allocation in multiples of backing storage if this enables derefing to work